# Show that the set $H = \{2^n: \in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of for $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: group-theory

Do we just use the subgroup criteria on this? Finding that it's closed, has inverse and identity within the subgroup?

But I still don't how does that prove the fact that's $H = \{2^n: \in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$, what if it's not a subset?

Comment: Currently it's not a subset. $0\in H$ but $0\notin \mathbb{Q}\setminus \{ 0\} $.

Comment: Sorry that's 2^n

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I'm sorry but how is $0 \in H$??? exp can never be identically zero.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Did you consdier that perhaps the question has been changed since my comment?

Answer (score 1):

Since $2^n$ is a non-zero rational number for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, indeed $H \subset \mathbb{Q} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$. Then as you said, $H$ is a subgroup by the subgroup criterion (where the group operation on $H$ is multiplication).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $H$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+,0)$, hence it is an infinite cyclic group. $(\mathbb{Q}/ \{0\},*,1)$ has many infinite cyclic subgroups, just take any no-trivial element $a \in \mathbb{Q}/\{0\}$ and look at the cyclic subgroup $<a>$. We have $<a> \cong H$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is correct but not an answer to the question, which asks for a proof that $H$ _is_ a subgroup, not that it's isomorphic to a subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

If $f\colon G_1\to G_2$ is a homomorphism of groups then its image is a subgroup of $G_2$.  Now the function $f(n)=2^n$ is a homomorphism of the group of integers under addition to the group of non-zero rationals under multiplication. Your $H$ is the image of this homomorphism.

Actially this shows more subsets of this kind are subgroups. All  $3^n$, or $800^n$ or $(59/1947)^n$ (with $n$ varying over all integers) are subgroups.